# Cannot get data from HTTP Response using UnityWebRequest in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, httprequest, azure-cognitive-services

Hey Unity and Microsoft PROs! I am trying to use the **Microsoft Bing Text to Speech API** in **Unity**, this API requires an **AccessToken** that will be passed in the request header. to get this token, I have sent my ***Authentication Key*** in the ***"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"*** header, and the the API will return back the access token that i can use next, this is a test of the API that retuns the Token in Postman.

[image: Testing the access token via Postman]

So this is the code to do this, but it doesn't work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static readonly string accessUri = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken";
    public string accessToken;

    public void Start()
    {
        WWWForm wwwForm = new WWWForm();
        Dictionary<string, string> headers = wwwForm.headers;
        headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = "a66ec1e2123784hf39f22e2dc2e760d13x";

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(accessUri, wwwForm);
        StartCoroutine(RequestToken(www));
    }

    public IEnumerator RequestToken(UnityWebRequest www)
    {
        yield return www;
        if (www.error == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("downloadedBytes : " + www.downloadedBytes);
            Debug.Log("certificateHandler : " + www.certificateHandler);
            Debug.Log("chunkedTransfer : " + www.chunkedTransfer);
            Debug.Log("downloadHandler : " + www.downloadHandler);
            Debug.Log("downloadProgress : " + www.downloadProgress);
            Debug.Log("isDone : " + www.isDone);
            Debug.Log("isNetworkError : " + www.isNetworkError);
            Debug.Log("method : " + www.method);
            Debug.Log("redirectLimit : " + www.redirectLimit);
            Debug.Log("responseCode : " + www.responseCode);
            Debug.Log("uploadedBytes : " + www.uploadedBytes);
            Debug.Log("useHttpContinue : " + www.useHttpContinue);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Error" + www.error);
        }
        var p = www.downloadHandler.data;
        Debug.Log("Access token: " + p);
    }
}
```

The result of this code :

[image]

I have already tried the **WWW class**, but this didn't work! and the **System.Net.Http**, but Unity wont accept this Library :/

Is there any way to do that, please?

Comment: For security concerns you probably shouldn't post your real API Key

Comment: I haven't worked with untiy in a while, but your yield return in the beginning seems fishy

Comment: Thank you very much @johnny5 , it is a trial API key, and it is already expired.
The yield return should be first because it will wait for the server response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a `www.SendWebRequest()` statement. Your code just states `yield return www;`, rather than `yield return www.SendWebRequest()`.

See this code example (from [UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) documentation):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class MyBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Upload());
    }

    IEnumerator Upload()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("myField", "myData");

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://www.my-server.com/myform", form))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Also, regarding the `Access token: System.Byte[]` output message with your code, note that the `DownloadHandler.text` property should be used rather than `DownloadHandler.data` for debugging the output. Currently, it is just printing the type of the property rather than its actual contents.)

EDIT: Note that I debugged the issue this way because `www.isDone` is false and `www.downloadProgress` is -1. This hints that the www request never sent or finished correctly. If it was an error, I think `www.isDone` would have likely been true with errors provided elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try with adding these in your request

```
request.Accept = @"application/json;text/xml";
request.ContentType = @"audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000";
```

and check if it's working.